# How to write a helper in Ruby on Rails to capture Haml blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, helper

I am writing a Rails helper method that will add wrapper html to captured content blocks and replace content_for method, such as

```
- content_for :header do
 //haml code
```

..would become

```
- content :header do
 //haml code
```

In order to do this I am using Haml and Ruby blocks. This is what it looks like

```
def content(name,&block)
 content_for name do
   capture_haml do
     haml_tag "div",{:id=>name.to_s} do
       haml_tag "div",{:id=>"#{name.to_s}_group"} do
         block
       end  
     end    
   end      
 end  
end
```

But I can't get this to work. There is no error message. It just doesn't show the block at all! I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I'd appreciate a second opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're doing roughly the right thing, but you aren't actually calling the block `#content` is passed. To do so, either use `block.call`, or Ruby's built-in `yield` statement.

Answer (score 0):

just change this

```
haml_tag "div",{:id=>"#{name.to_s}_group"} do
  yield
end
```

to

```
haml_tag "div",{:id=>"#{name.to_s}_group"},&block
```

Comment: These two are actually exactly equivalent in behavior. (The `&block` version may be slightly more performant, but these days they're about the same.) As @nex3 points out, though, the OP wasn't calling `yield`, but was simply returning the `block` without calling it.